# What's the best way to define a variable within the scope of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to define variables within scope of `paginate()`. However, any variable defined with `this` (e.g. `this.parentlist`) is not available within the jQuery `click` method

```
var paginate = function(elt) {
          //would like to define variables within scope of paginate()
          //however, any variable defined with this (e.g. this.parentlist) is not available within the jQuery click method
          this.parentlist = elt.find('ul');
          var listitems = elt.find('li');
          this.listcount = this.list.find('li').size();
          var showitems = '3';

          this.numberofpages = ~~((this.count / this.show) + 1);

          this.parentlist.after('<ul class="links"></ul>');

          for(i=1;i<=this.numberofpages;i++) {
            $('.links').append('<li><a href="#'+i+'">'+i+'</a></li>')
          };

          //click a link
          $('.links a').click(function() {
            //this.parentlist is not available here
            listitems.hide();
            this.start = listitems.index() * showitems;
            this.end = (this.start + 1) * showitems;
            this.selected = listitems.slice(this.start,this.end).show().addClass('selected');
            console.log(this.selected);
            console.log(this.parentlist);
          }); 
  };

  paginate($('.pages'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `var` keyword to declare a variable within the current scope.

```
//For example:
var paginate = function(){

    // create a local variable (local to "paginate function")
    var myvar = 7;

    // create the click handler
    $('.links a').click(function() {

        // access the local variable
        alert(myvar);

    });
}
```

The `myvar` variable is available "within" the click handler anonymous function because they were both declared "within" the same scope (the paginate function).

However, once you're inside the anonymous function, `this` refers to the calling object of that function and not the function that it was declared in.  If you need access to `this` as the "paginate" caller, then you can cache the `this` variable like others are saying:  `var that = this;` <-- this is declaring a local variable (like above) and setting its value to `this`.

So, in your example, you can change it like this:

```
var paginate = function(elt) {

      var parentlist = elt.find('ul');
      var listitems = elt.find('li');
      var listcount = this.list.find('li').size();
      var showitems = '3';

      var numberofpages = ~~((this.count / this.show) + 1);

      parentlist.after('<ul class="links"></ul>');

      for(i=1;i<=numberofpages;i++) {
        $('.links').append('<li><a href="#'+i+'">'+i+'</a></li>')
      };

      //click a link
      $('.links a').click(function() {
        //this.parentlist is not available here
        listitems.hide();
        this.start = listitems.index() * showitems;
        this.end = (this.start + 1) * showitems;
        this.selected = listitems.slice(this.start,this.end).show().addClass('selected');
        console.log(this.selected);
        console.log(parentlist);
      }); 
};

paginate($('.pages'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I also found this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1):

That is because inside `click` event handler `this` points to anchor element on which the event handler is attached.

You have to declare a variable outside the handler and then use it. It will still be inside `paginate` function scope. Try this

```
var paginate = function(elt) {
          //would like to define variables within scope of paginate()
          //however, any variable defined with this (e.g. this.parentlist) is not available within the jQuery click method
          var parentlist = elt.find('ul');

          ..
          ..
          //click a link
          $('.links a').click(function() {

            //this.parentlist is not available here
            //Use parentlist instead of this.parentlist 
            ..
            ..

          }); 
  };

  paginate($('.pages'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, it is better to declare parentlist as a var function paginate()

The variable will then be accessible in the click function enclosed in the paginate function.

```
var paginate = function () {
     var parentlist = "some value";

     $('#selector').click(function () {
         alert(parentlist);
     });
};
```

Comment: -1 The `this` in the given scope is a `window` object. Repeated calls to `paginate()` will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't prefix your variables with `this.`. The `this` in the scope of `paginate()` is the global scope (window).

If you define it as `var parentlist = elt.find('ul');`, the `parentlist` will be available as is inside the click handler.

Comment: @RobHruska that is both weird and irrelevant. Weird because it is not returning anything and there is no prototype defined. Irrelevant because `click` handler defined inside `paginate()` will form closure over variables in the same scope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work . There is no need to create additional namespace for them.